# Display Posts that fit a certain criteria on Category pages

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, plugin-list-category-post

I wish to display posts that fit a certain criteria on a category page. Something like a search filter applied, to several such category pages.

For example, to display all movies by Chris Pratt that grossed over 10 million dollars. Or All movies with Chris Pratt and Zoe Saldana, etc.

How / where would I have to look for a good tutorial on how to do the same?

Would it go into the realms of custom fields with custom taxonomies? Please advise if possible.

Comment: As you have some notion of what's involved, it would be best to try a few ideas and to post your code, so that others can help you improve it.

Comment: How are you storing that Chris Pratt was in the movie? As a category / taxonomy, or as an actor list in post meta, or something else? Ditto grossed $10m: is that a category, or are you storing the gross value in post meta, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I creates a shortcode for the same. I need to display all the post of a particular category in a specific format. So added a function in php to add shortcode with input as 'category name' and show in the format I want. This [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/) helped.